Multiplatform Compose state does not update font change in Text on Android (on IOS it works well)
we are working on some kind of reader experience for the users. We are trying to allow the user to change font size, color, etc. One of the options is to change the font completely.
What we faced, is that it does not work on Android (well maybe kind of does), but works well on iOS.
The whole example project can be found here ->
https://github.com/fandomWojtek/Test_ReaderApp
We use Compose Multiplatform 1.6.10, Kotlin 2.0.0, Compose Resources
And now to the point ->
we have a mutable state of Text Style
    data class Style(val color: Color = Color.Black, val fontSize: Float = 14f, val fontFamily: FontResource = Res.font.rubik_regular)
    
    
    @Composable
    fun TestScreen() {
        var styleState by remember {
            mutableStateOf(Style())
        }
        Column(modifier = Modifier.background(Color.White)) {
            LazyColumn(modifier = Modifier.weight(1.0f), verticalArrangement = Arrangement.spacedBy(24.dp)) {
                for (i in 0..100) {
                    item {
                        Text(
                            staticText,
                            style = style.copy(color = styleState.color, fontSize = styleState.fontSize.sp, fontFamily = FontFamily(Font(styleState.fontFamily, FontWeight.Normal)))
                            )
                    }
                }
            }
           //Some code removed to readability
            Row(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(), horizontalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceEvenly) {
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp).clickable {
                        styleState = (styleState.copy(fontFamily = Res.font.rubik_regular))
                    },
                    text = "roboto",
                    style = style
                )
    
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp).clickable {
                        styleState = (styleState.copy(fontFamily = Res.font.HelveticaNeueMedium))
                    },
                    text = "helvetica",
                    style = style
                )
    
                Text(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(16.dp).clickable {
                        styleState = (styleState.copy(fontFamily = Res.font.COMICSANS))
                    },
                    text = "Comic Sans",
                    style = style
                )
            }
        }
    }

And to our surprise, it does not work on Android, the Text is doing a recomposition, but it does not update on the screen (when you scroll Text out of the screen and then scroll back, it has a new Font)

What is odd (or not :P ) works perfectly fine on IOS

tested on both debug and release versions of the Android app, on different devices, different Android SDK level

Have you tried downgrading to kotlin version 1.9? This may be a bug in version 2.0, in which case it should be reported to the issue tracker (which is not stack overflow) so that it can be fixed as soon as possible

actually, I didn't, I will try it

@PhilDukhov the same behavior can be observed on kotlin 1.9.23 and compose multiplatform 1.6.2 and 1.6.10 . Do you think that I should open an issue on the compose multiplatform repository?

It has been fixed in 1.6.11

This is a bug of Font composable. Reported it here.
Until it's fixed you can reset it's value manually using key. Use FontHotfix instead of Font for now:
@SuppressLint("ComposableNaming")
@Composable
// TODO: replace with system `Font` when https://github.com/JetBrains/compose-multiplatform/issues/4863 is fixed
fun FontHotfix(
    resource: FontResource,
    weight: FontWeight = FontWeight.Normal,
    style: FontStyle = FontStyle.Normal,
) = key(resource) {
    Font(resource = resource, weight = weight, style = style)
}


Many thanks Phil, cheers to you mate
